# Jquery get selector from on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('body').on('click', 'input, button, #el, li, .classTest, input[name=nametest], div > a.more', function(target) {
    console.log($(this).selector);
});
```

How do I implement a function selector(), that returns:

```
'input', if you click on input;
'button', if you click on button;
'li', if you click on li;
'.classTest', if you click on .classTest;
'input[name=nametest]', if you click on input[name=nametest];
'div > a.more', if you click on div > a.more;
```

Comment: `this.nodeName` and `.toLowerCase()` if you don't like upper case.

Comment: `"'" + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + "'"` heh

Comment: Edited my ask..

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', function(event) {
   var target=event.target;
    alert(target.type);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Click">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I would probably do it this way as well. Looks like he is looking for event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible, but it requires a little more work since jQuery removed the `.selector` property in jQuery 1.9.

First, note that an element's full selector may be very long with many classes, an ID, another attributes, etc. You are only interested, I presume, in getting the matching selector that you passed *to jQuery*. Also, it's quite possible that the element matches multiple selectors; my answer controls for that by separating relevant selectors by a string; you may wish a more sophisticated combination.

I use `.is()` and a string variable containing your selector which you have access to in your event handler. The basic idea is, go through all the selectors and concatenate the ones that match `$(element).is(selector)`.

```js
function selector ( element, selectorList ) {
      var selector = "";
      for ( var i=0; i<selectorList.length; ++i ) {     
            if ( $(element).is(selectorList[i]) ) {
                if ( selector.length && selector[selector.length-1] != "," ) { selector += ","; }
                selector += selectorList[i];
            }
      }
      return selector;
}

$("document").ready(function(){
  
var selectorList = 'input, button, #el, li, .classTest, input[name=nametest], div > a.more';

$('body').on('click', selectorList, function(target) {
     alert(selector(this,selectorList.split(",")));
});
  
});
```

```css
* { cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me!</button>

<div id='el' >This is #el, click me</div>
```